# How can I resize dynamic vertex buffer in Directx 12

Tags: c++, directx

I'm writing a directx App and I want to resize my VertexBuffer as vertex's size and indices' size changes with each every frame.

I wonder if there are some special ways to handle with minimal costs. I think it is not awkward to create new constant buffer in every frame. 
Is there any possible solution for me?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you can do without relocating is: create a VertexBuffer / IndexBuffer large enough for all the cases, and when drawing on the screen, use only the number of indices you will use.